# Disabling dictation within the app

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, siri, dictating

Is there any way to disable the dictation key?  I really don't want to create a custom keyboard for this.  I assumed it would be like the UIResponder, but that only applies to textview's shared menu; which only contains copy, cut, and paste, etc.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think the main question is why would you want to? It is only detrimental to your app to not have voice input. It makes your app less accessible.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Might be, but no one has answered it...

Comment: @mjb162 Our app involves secure data.  And the transcribing is done on the Apple's server, which could be a security risk.

Comment: @TakeshiKaga good reason. As for your answer, I will see what I can dig up, but more than likely it will probably be a private API. Meaning you will not be able to publish to the app store.

Comment: @TakeshiKaga That does not justify a duplicate question.