# iOS SDK: Disable text dictation for UITextField

Tags: ios, sdk, siri

Is it possible to disable text dictation for an UITextField or the whole app?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148635/disabling-dictation-within-the-app?rq=1

Comment: Thanks!

That solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12079125/1074188